# why is my transparent object is showing image?

Tags: image, transparency

i'm trying to make Sight for my AK-47,[image], but when i tried to make a glass for the sight it showing some random image, [image] this is the setting i did [image],
how to make it transparent 100% like a normal glass for my sight

Comment: You are in "Material Preview" mode. The reflection you are seeing is generated by a hidden HDRI. Switch to "Rendered Preview" mode, to see the scene with the lighting you set up. (Farthest right of the 4 little circles in the top-right of the viewport). I would also recommend reducing the Alpha of your image to make it transparent, and switch the Blend Mode (further down in material properties) to anything but "opaque".

Comment: You have to enable the screen space refraction in the render properties too. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj6MgfhqOr4